# how to handle no row at position error messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I am getting an error:

> There is no row at position 4

This means that the `DataTable` doesn't have the row number I specified.

Below is an example:

```
protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["ClickCount"] == null)
        Session["ClickCount"] = 0;

    int ClickCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ClickCount"]) + 1;
    Session["ClickCount"] = ClickCount;

    DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter eobj = new DAL.TicketsDataSetTableAdapters.TicketDetailsTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = eobj.GetTicketUpdates(txtSupportRef.Text);

    if (ClickCount > dt.Rows.Count)
    {
        // HOW DO WE HANDLE THE ERROR?
    }
    txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[ClickCount - 1]["NextStep"].ToString();
}
```

I have 3 rows in my `DataTable` and if click the button again it will give me the error message above.

What is the best way to handle this error message?

Should I exit out of the the `if statement` and then present the user with a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *disable* the `btnNext` button:

```
if (ClickCount > dt.Rows.Count)
{
    btnNext.Enabled= false;
    // Also with a message
}
else
{
    btnNext.Enabled= true;
    txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[ClickCount - 1]["NextStep"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are checking the `ClickCount` by using `if (ClickCount > dt.Rows.Count)` but accessing the value outside the loop, make use as follows:

```
if (ClickCount < dt.Rows.Count)
    {
       txtNextStep.Text = dt.Rows[ClickCount - 1]["NextStep"].ToString();
    }
   else{btnNext.Enabled=false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do proper check before using 'Clickcount'

```
if (ClickCount > dt.Rows.Count)
{
    // show a proper message to user
}
else if (ClickCount < dt.Rows.Count)
{
    //
}
else
{
    //
}
```